# Unix: extracting data from a .dat file and inserting into SQL database?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, extract

Hi so I have around 1000 .dat files that I need to process, each with data of about 1,000 users. The file format is as follows (in reality, the data is of course filled in: John, 18, john@email.com for example - I only numbered them to highlight the ordering issue):

```
<Name> Name_1
<Age> Age_1 
<Email> Email_1

<Name> Name_2
<Age> Age_2
<Email> Email_2

(...etc...)
```

So let's say I have a database table, with two coloumns (name and email), what would be the best way for me to extract the data and fill the database using Unix/Shell/Bash? Currently I am using the following to try and extract the data:

```
for file in $1/*;
do
    grep "<Name>" $file |
    sed 's/<Name>//g' >> temp.txt

    grep "<Email>" $file |
    sed 's/<Email>//g'>> temp.txt
done
```

And although this extracts the right data, the output is as follows:

```
(--File 1--)
Name_1
Name_2
Email_1
Email_2
(--File 2--)
Name_1001
Name_1002
Email_1001
Email_1002
(etc)
```

In reality, I was thinking it would be better if I could have the data be extracted in this order instead, though I don't know if that is possible to do using grep.

```
Name_1
Email_1

Name_2
Email_2

(etc)
```

Since if the data was extracted like this, then I could just store the values in shell variables and then use the following to add to the database:

```
sqlite db.sql INSERT INTO users VALUES ($name, $email);
```

Or something along those lines, if that would work.

Anyway, hopefully I have explained myself semi-clearly, though if anyone could help me out on this I'd appreciate it massively. Effectively I'm asking if it is possible to grep one user, then an email, then another user and the corresponding email...as opposed to how grep seems to work, by extracting ALL the users, then ALL the emails. Maybe there's another function that would do the job nicely?

Cheers!

Comment: Does your data actually contain the _1, _2 etc? John_1, 21_1, John@email_1 ----- Doe_2, 22_2,Doe@email_2.?

Comment: No, it is completely random like john@email.com as you mentioned. I will specify that. I only used numbers to show the ordering...

Comment: I figured that, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Haha no worries. Shame I can't upvote you...guess my account has too low a reputation or something :(

Comment: As others have answered, `awk` is probably a good bet; outputting insert statements as they do is good, but you may also want to consider output in CSV format because "import from csv" is commonly an easy way to get data into a database.  Another possibility is using `perl` with a database connection module, to actually do the inserts during the file processing.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good problem for `grep` and `sed`. I recommend `awk`.  An **untested** first cut:

```
awk '
/<Name>/ {name=$1}
/<Email>/ {emails[name] = $1}

END {for (n in emails) {print n, print email[n]}}
' *.dat
```

You could also try

```
END {for (n in emails) {print "sqlite db.sql INSERT INTO users VALUES (" n "," email");"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are a great fan of `grep`. Give it a try:

```
grep -Po '(?<=(Name|mail)>[\t\s])(.*)$' file | `xargs -n2 printf "sqlite db.sql INSERT INTO users VALUES (%s, %s)\n"`
```

The first part is doing a positive lookbehind to fetch the relevant info. Lookbehind doesn't support varibale lengths, that why `mail` is being used instead of `Email`. It outputs :

```
Name_1
Email_1
Name_2
Email_2
```

The `xargs -n2` is combining name and email as follows:

```
Name_1 Email_1
Name_2 Email_2
```

This is formatted by the `printf` and is being executed. Hope it helps.

Now please don't tell me your grep doesn't support `-P` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in (GNU) sed, altough the awk script is much simpler.

**dat2sql.sed:**

```
/<NAME>/I H  # store name
/<EMAIL>/I {
  H;         # store email
  g          # get stored strings

  s/<[^>]+>\s+//gI; # remove <NAME> and <EMAIL>

  s/^$\n/sqlite db.sql INSERT INTO users VALUES ("/;
  s/\n/", "/;
  s/$/" );/;

  p                 # print results
  s/.*//g;  x;      # clear hold space
}
```

Use it like this: `sed -rn -f dat2sql.sed your_file`.

The prerequisite is that Name is before Email for each record in the file.